# How to draw a ring with green color walking thru the ring in 3 senconds in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I am a new to AFRAME, I expect there will be a ring(or the cursor) being colored with green little by little when the cursor moves on someone entity, this action will notify how long time remaining to trigger the fuse. Can AFRAME do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here is an example with scale:

https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/components/cursor.html#adding-visual-feedback

```
<a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500"
          position="0 0 -1"
          geometry="primitive: ring"
          material="color: black; shader: flat">
  <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale"
               fill="backwards" from="0.1 0.1 0.1" to="1 1 1"></a-animation>
  <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale"
               fill="forwards" from="1 1 1" to="0.1 0.1 0.1"></a-animation>
</a-entity>
```

To do a circle, you can animation the circle's thetaLength rather than scale to make it draw a circle as it fuses.

```
<a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500"
          position="0 0 -1"
          geometry="primitive: ring"
          material="color: black; shader: flat">
  <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale"
               fill="backwards" from="0.1 0.1 0.1" to="1 1 1"></a-animation>
  <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="geometry.thetaLength"
               fill="forwards" from="0" to="360"></a-animation>
</a-entity>
```

Comment: cool just make sure to use animation component instead these days